# How can I make a Editable gridView in yii-booster bootstrap widget with one of its column

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

I'm new to this. I want to make grid under grid structure so i used the Yii-booster Extensions but its not working

**My code:**

```
Extensions:
    protected/extensions/booster
```

MY Module

```
   protected/modules/delivery/controllers
```

DefaultController.php

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider = new models\db\DNote(); 
        $columns = $dataProvider->getColumnsDelivery();
        $this->render('index',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,'columns'=>$columns));
    }
public function actionRelational()
{
    Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
     Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = false;
    $dataProvider = new models\db\DNoteLine();
    $this->renderPartial('_relational', array(
        'gridDataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ), false, true);
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

            $this->widget('ext.booster.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
            //'filter'=>$dataProvider,
            'type'=>'striped bordered',
            'id'=>'DeliveryNote-grid', 
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider->search(),
            'template' => "{items}",
            'columns' => array_merge(array(
            array(
                'class'=>'application.extensions.booster.widgets.TbRelationalColumn',
                'name' => 'Edit',
                'url' => $this->createUrl('default/relational'),
                'value'=> '"test-subgrid"',
                'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:function(tr,rowid,data){
                    bootbox.alert("I have afterAjax events too!
                    This will only happen once for row with id: "+rowid);
                }'
                )
            ),$columns),
            ));
?>
```

_relational.php

```
<?php $this->widget('application.extensions.booster.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
            //'filter'=>$DataProvider,
            'type'=>'striped bordered',
            'id'=>'Deliverysample-grid', 
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider->search(),
            'template' => "{items}",
            'columns' => $columns,          
            ));
?>
```

TbRelationalcolumn.php

```
public function registerClientScript() {

        $booster= Booster::getBooster();
            $booster->registerAssetCss('bootstrap-relational.css');

        /** @var $cs CClientScript */
        $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
        if ($this->afterAjaxUpdate !== null) {
            if ((!$this->afterAjaxUpdate instanceof CJavaScriptExpression)
                && (strpos($this->afterAjaxUpdate,'js:') !== 0)
            ) {
                $this->afterAjaxUpdate = new CJavaScriptExpression($this->afterAjaxUpdate);
            }
        } else {
            $this->afterAjaxUpdate = 'js:$.noop';
        }

        $this->ajaxErrorMessage = CHtml::encode($this->ajaxErrorMessage);
        $afterAjaxUpdate = CJavaScript::encode($this->afterAjaxUpdate);
        $span = count($this->grid->columns);

        //$loadingPic = CHtml::image($booster->getAssetsUrl() . '/img/loading.gif');
        $loadingPic = CHtml::image( '../img/loading.gif');
        $cache = $this->cacheData ? 'true' : 'false';
        $data = !empty($this->submitData) && is_array($this->submitData) ? $this->submitData : 'js:{}';
        $data = CJavascript::encode($data);
        list($parentId) = explode('_',$this->id);
        //die ($parentId + $this->cssClass);
        $js = <<<EOD
$(document).on('click','#{$parentId} .{$this->cssClass}', function(){
        alert ($parentId + $this->cssClass); 
    var span = $span;
    var that = $(this);
    var status = that.data('status');
    var rowid = that.data('rowid');
    var tr = $('#relatedinfo'+rowid);
    var parent = that.parents('tr').eq(0);
    var afterAjaxUpdate = {$afterAjaxUpdate};

    if (status && status=='on'){return}
    that.data('status','on');

    if (tr.length && !tr.is(':visible') && {$cache})
    {
        tr.slideDown();
        that.data('status','off');
        return;
    }else if (tr.length && tr.is(':visible'))
    {
        tr.slideUp();
        that.data('status','off');
        return;
    }
    if (tr.length)
    {
        tr.find('td').html('{$loadingPic}');
        if (!tr.is(':visible')){
            tr.slideDown();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var td = $('<td/>').html('{$loadingPic}').attr({'colspan':$span});
        tr = $('<tr/>').prop({'id':'relatedinfo'+rowid}).append(td);
        /* we need to maintain zebra styles :) */
        var fake = $('<tr class="hide"/>').append($('<td/>').attr({'colspan':$span}));
        parent.after(tr);
        tr.after(fake);
    }
    var data = $.extend({$data}, {id:rowid});
    $.ajax({
        url: '{$this->url}',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            tr.find('td').html(data);
            that.data('status','off');
            if ($.isFunction(afterAjaxUpdate))
            {
                afterAjaxUpdate(tr,rowid,data);
            }
        },
        error: function()
        {
            tr.find('td').html('{$this->ajaxErrorMessage}');
            that.data('status','off');
        }
    });
});
EOD;
        $cs->registerScript(__CLASS__ . '#' . $this->id, $js);
    }
```

Im getting the header grid . when im clicking on **EDIT (test-subgrid)** ,Nothing happens even i didn't get an alert message.
Please anyone help to resolve this problem

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: no Errors at same time click event not enable

Comment: Do you see correctly generated code via CTRL + U

Comment: I have downloaded the extensions from http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/ yiibooster-4.0.1.zip file and extracted under protected/extensions/booster

Comment: editable column must have the 'editable' prop setting the attributes for the editable field see http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/editable/view/column.html

Comment: hey man ... I can not see you are using any TbEditableColumn (s) !!!

Comment: im using TbRelationalColumn http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView#gridcolumns